# Retrofit- Android : Request method not accepted

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp, android-webservice

In my android application, i am trying to use retrofit to make api calls. I want to perform user registration using retrofit. The problem is that, api call is executed and debugger also goes to `onResponse()`, but my api returns response message as 'Request method not accepted'. I checked with postman, it works properly. in postman, i am passing values as form-data. please help me to solve this issue. here is my code :

```
public interface RegisterAPI {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Register.php")
    Call<RegisterPojo> insertUser(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("c_password") String c_password
    );
}
```

Activity

```
     Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();

          RegisterAPI service = retrofit.create(RegisterAPI.class);


          Call<RegisterPojo> call = service.insertUser(
                            edtUname.getText().toString(), edtEmail.getText().toString(),
                            edtPassword.getText().toString(), edtConfirmPassword.getText().toString());

     call.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterPojo>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<RegisterPojo> call, Response<RegisterPojo> response) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
//HERE IT SHOWS "Request method not accepted"
                            Log.e("msg", response.body().getMsg());
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, response.body().getMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<RegisterPojo> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("msg", "Failed");
                    }
                });
```

RegisterPojo

```
public class RegisterPojo {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Integer status;

    @SerializedName("msg")
    @Expose
    private String msg;

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.sample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.5.1@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    //    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
}
```

please tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: put  device log here

Comment: your api might accept GET method only.

Comment: No, it accepts POST method. i executed same api with POST method in postman. it works perfectly with that.

Comment: remove .php from @POST("Register.php")

Comment: and use `@POST("/Register")` like that .............And also edit your logcat error on question....

Comment: @sushildlh i have alreday added `/` at the end of `BASE_URL`.

Comment: @AlexChengalan removing `.php` from end, gives `404 not found`

Comment: is the `RegisterPojo` in correct format?

Comment: please post image of your Postman about request and response ....

Comment: @AlexChengalan yes, `RegisterPojo` is of correct format.

Answer (score 1):

In `onResponse()`, its better to check successful query execution and then get the message from the body of `Response` object.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterPojo>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<RegisterPojo> call, Response<RegisterPojo> response){
        if(response.isSuccess())
        {
            // Now try to get message from the body
        }
        else
        {
            // Error occurred while execution
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<RegisterPojo> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("msg", "Failed");
    }
});
```

If `isSuccess()` is false, then the error message can be fetched like this:

```
response.errorBody().string()
```

And if response is success, and you cannot get the data then the problem is with your `RegisterPojo` model. The conversion library which you are using cannot convert JSON to object. Also make sure, you are implementing `Serializable` in this model.

Check this [link](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/) and verify `RegisterPojo` is in correct format or not.

For me, initializing Retrofit like this worked:

```
private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC)
    .serializeNulls()
    .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build();
```

Comment: i checked, its going inside `response.isSuccess()`. That means api call was successful.

Comment: @zanky See my updated answer. Also make sure `RegisterPojo` is in correct format.

Comment: i added  `RegisterPojo` in my question.

Comment: Try adding **Serializable** Eg:  `public class RegisterPojo implements Serializable`

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare interface as `Call<RegisterPojo> insertUser(@Body UserClass user);`
if you can check your request from logging interceptor you will see your request body as;

> username: name, email: email@m.com ...

but it should be as;

> { "username": name, "email": email@m.com ... }

idk why but i made work my request as this(with body and class). i am sure there is a way to make to make it work with field but i could not found.